# Associative law for infinite unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A$ be a function s.t. $\mbox{dom}(A)=I\times J$.

Prove that: $\bigcup_{i \in I,j \in J}A_{ij}=\bigcup_{i \in I}\left ( \bigcup_{j \in J}A_{ij}\right )$.

The problem is that I cannot interpret the right-hand side of the equation.

By the book, if $A$ is a function with $\mbox{dom}A=I$,

$\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}:=\bigcup\mbox{rng}(A)$.

On the left-hand side of the equality I have to prove, we clearly have a function.

On the right-hand side, no matter how I rearrange it, I cannot interpret the nested union by definition.

Let me explain.

By definition, on the left-hand side I have

$\bigcup_{i \in I,j \in J}A_{ij}\\
:=\bigcup_{(i,j)\in I\times J}A(i,j)\\
:=\bigcup\mbox{rng}A.$

Let's see an example with:

$I\times J=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\},\\
A(0,0)=\{0\},\\
A(0,1)=\{1\},\\
A(1,0)=\{2\},\\
A(1,1)=\{3\}.\\$

Then 
$A=\{\\
((0,0),\{0\}),\\ 
((0,1),\{1\}),\\ 
((1,0),\{2\}),\\ 
((1,1),\{3\})\}.$

And in the following calculations we can see what we get left-hand side.

$\mbox{rng}A\\
=\{y:\exists x[(x,y)\in A]\}\\
=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$.

$\bigcup_{(i,j)\in I\times J}A(i,j)\\
=\bigcup \mbox{rng}A\\
=\{x:\exists y \in \mbox{rng}A(x \in y)\}\\
=\{x:\exists y \in \{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}(x \in y)\}\\
=\{0,1,2,3\}$.

For the right hand side we define the following functions.

Let $i \in \{0,1\}$.

$A\upharpoonright (\{i\}\times \{0,1\})=A\cap (\{(i,0),(i,1)\}\times \mbox{rng}A),\\
A\upharpoonright (\{0\}\times \{0,1\})=A\cap (\{(0,0),(0,1)\}\times \mbox{rng}A),\\
A\upharpoonright (\{1\}\times \{0,1\})=A\cap (\{(1,0),(1,1)\}\times \mbox{rng}A)$.

We have then:

$\mbox{rng}A\upharpoonright (\{0\}\times \{0,1\}),\\
=\{y:\exists x[(x,y)\in A\upharpoonright (\{0\}\times \{0,1\})]\},\\
=\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$.

$\mbox{rng}A\upharpoonright (\{1\}\times \{0,1\}),\\
=\{y:\exists x[(x,y)\in A\upharpoonright (\{1\}\times \{0,1\})]\},\\
=\{\{2\},\{3\}\}$.

$\bigcup_{j \in J}A\upharpoonright (\{0\}\times \{0,1\})_{j}\\
:=\bigcup \mbox{rng}A\upharpoonright (\{0\}\times \{0,1\})\\
=\{x:\exists y \in \mbox{rng}A\upharpoonright (\{0\}\times \{0,1\})(x \in y)\}\\
=\{x:\exists y \in \{\{0\},\{1\}\}(x \in y)\}\\
=\{0,1\}$

$\bigcup_{j \in J}A\upharpoonright (\{1\}\times \{0,1\})_{j}\\
=\{1,2\}$.

So it is clear by this example that taking the union for $i=1,2$ we get $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Still, I don't have the definition for the nested union so I cannot really prove the theorem not knowing what am dealing with.

Is there a more general definition of infinite union I am not aware of?

Notation from: Introduction to Set Theory, Donald Monk.

Comment: What bugs me is that in $\bigcup_{j \in J}A_{ij}$, like you're saying, you have to "fix" $i$ for $f_{i}$ to be a function of $j$. Isolated it cannot strictly be interpreted by the definition. I will look into the $\bigcup \mbox{rng}(g)$ you have suggested, does that solve the problem? Also thank you for the wikipedia reference.

Comment: I have moved my comments to an answer. The solution is that the $A$ on the right hand side is not literally the $A$ on the left - the $A$ on the right is a Curried version of the $A$ on the left.  This convention about Currying is completely standard and ubiquitous,  so I am not surprised to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say $\bigcup_{j∈J} A_{ij}$ they are talking about the range of the function $f_i:j\mapsto A_{ij}$, in which $i$ is constant and the domain is $J$. It makes perfect sense to take the range of this function, even if we have not given it a specific name. So the double union is $\bigcup_{i \in I} (\bigcup \text{rng}(f_i))$.

If we then let $g\colon i\mapsto \bigcup \text{rng}(f_i)$, with domain $I$, then the overall double union $\bigcup_{i \in I}\bigcup_{j \in J} A_{ij}$ is just $\bigcup \text{rng}(g)$.

The method underlying this is the standard identification between maps from $(I \times J)$ to a set $X$ and maps from $I$ to maps from $J$ to $X$, that is,  $\text{Hom}(I \times J,X) \cong \text{Hom}(I,\text{Hom}(J,X))$. This is known as [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Writing $\bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} A_{ij}$, when $A\colon I \times J \to X$, is intended to silently invoke the Curried version of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask whether the $\bigcup \mbox{rng}(g)$ you have suggested is a formulation of the right-hand side by the definition provided in my question? I haven't yet looked into it. Edit: I get it now, but the "problem" again is that in $g:i\mapsto\bigcup \mbox{rng}(f_{i})$ we have to "fix" $i$ in $\bigcup \mbox{rng}(f_{i})$ to have a function, like we both already said. I will look into the wikipedia article you have suggested though.

Comment: Yes, looking formally I would regard $\bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} A_{ij}$ to be $\bigcup \text{rng}(g)$ where $g\colon i \mapsto \bigcup \text{rng}(f_i)$, where for each $i$ we have $f_i \colon j \mapsto A_{ij}$.  But rather than writing out all these definitions of $g$ and $f_i$, it is typical to just write $\bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} A_{ij}$ and let the reader understand what is meant.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is similar to the approach I used in the example in the question, in which I restricted the function $A$ into two separate domains $\{i\}\times\{0,1\}$ (the domain of $A$ being $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$) for the two values of $i$, obtaining $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I think that is right - if you look at $A \upharpoonright \{i\} \times J$, you don't quite get my $f_i$, but almost.  I would define $f_i = \{ (j,x) : j \in J \land ((i,j),x) \in A\}$. This definition defines $f_i$ uniformly from $i$, which allows us to define $g$ using the set existence axiom of set theory. We get the union as $ \{ y : (\exists i) [  y \in \bigcup \text{rng}(f_i)]\} = \{ y : (\exists i) [ (\exists x \in \text{rng}(f_i)) y \in x]\} = \{ y : (\exists i) [ (\exists j) [ y \in f_i(j)]]\} = \{ y : (\exists i)(\exists j) (\exists x) [ ((i,j),x) \in A \land y \in x]\}$.

Comment: I get what you're saying.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Forget that theorem about rng. What you want to prove is obvious/trivial. Show that $x$ is an element of the RHS if and only if $x$ is an element of the LHS.

Probably starting like so: $x\in\bigcup_i\bigcup_j A_{i,j}$ if and only if there exists $i$ such that $x\in\bigcup_jA_{i,j}$.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I already know how to prove it using the naive approach.

Comment: There's no  indication in your question that what I wrote is not what you asked. Also no indication that you already know how to prove it -  if fact "I cannot really prove the theorem" directly contradicts that.

Comment: When I have a function $A$ with domain $I$, $\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}:=\cup\mbox{rng}A=\{x:\exists y\in \mbox{rng}A(x \in y)\}=\{x:\exists i \in I(x \in A(i))\}$. I can blindly use the latter for the right-hand side, but in the nested union I cannot have a function, since it depends on the variable $i$. How are nested unions defined?

Comment: @james-r  I really don't see why you care about that result about rng. Regading how nested unions are defined, I answered that above, in that answer you said wasn't what you were asking: "Nested" unions are just unions, defined like any other union: By definition, $\bigcup_i\bigcup_j A_{i,j}$ is the set of $x$ such that there exists $i$ with $x\in\bigcup_j A_{i,j}$.

Comment: @james-r Also  you're contradicting yourself. If you don't know what $\bigcup_i\bigcup_j A_{i,j}$ means you can't possibly already know how to prove the equality.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @james-r Why are you repeating yourself? If in fact my answer has nothing to do with the question that you meant to ask then the question you actually asked doesn't ask the question you meant to  ask.